# Show other users near your location?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working on iPhone app for my club. So, in one part of app I need to show how far away are other users from me, my location (in meters or kilometers). I was searching how to do it, and best option seems over Parse.com... Anyone can help me out, give some hint or usefull comment? Would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse.com have a good [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS) and [sample apps](https://parse.com/samples). I believe that [Anywall](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall) and [Geolocations](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/geolocations) tutorial will help.

**EDIT**
The basic idea is periodically save current user location to Parse.com and query for other users locations (maybe within some bounds).
You can track user location using `CLLocationManager`, or using `userLocation` property of `MKMapView` (if you set `showsUserLocation`).
Than you can attach location to `PFUser` and save to `Parse.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I read almost everything on their site, but still I have no clue how to replace Annotations on map with other user locations? If you understand what I'm after.

Comment: Yea, tracking is simple, that shouldn't make me problems. But how can I "call back all locations" once the locations are sent to parse.com, how can I show locations of all users (based on my criteria ofc, in within 100 meters or so)?

Comment: Check [PFGeoPoint](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo/iOS) - is designed exactly for your needs and you can easily [query](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#geo-query/iOS) Parse to return geoPoints within some bounds.

Comment: Hmmmm think I will play with this codes a bit more, maybe I can do what I've planed. And again thank you, no matter if "thank you" is needed or not :)